# Group by excluding Null - tsql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I have a script below:

```
    ;;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT 
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC,MAX(SecurityName)) AS [Rank]
            ,   ReportingDate
            ,   PortfolioID
            ,   PortfolioNme
            ,   MAX(SecurityName)                               AS SecurityName
            ,   CAST(SUM(Percentage) AS DECIMAL(22,1))          AS [Weight]
            ,   SEDOL
            ,   MAX(ISIN)                                       AS ISIN
        FROM @Worktable as WT

        WHERE WT.IssueType2 <> '010' AND WT.IssueType2 <> '055' AND WT.IssueType1 <> '110' -- To remove CASH and FX and Collateral

        GROUP BY    WT.ReportingDate
                ,   WT.PortfolioID
                ,   WT.PortfolioNme
                ,   WT.SEDOL
    )

    SELECT 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR, ReportingDate, 103)  AS ReportingDate
        , PortfolioID                           AS FundCode
        , PortfolioNme                          AS FundName
        , SecurityName                          AS InstrumentName
        , [Rank]
        , [Weight]                              AS Percentage
        , SEDOL
        , ISIN
    FROM CTE

    WHERE [Rank] <= 10

    ORDER BY ReportingDate, PortfolioID, [Rank], [Weight] DESC
```

I'm grouping by SEDOL as i want to group same SEDOLs together, however this is causing the NULLS to group together.  I've tried changing the script by adding a MAX around the SEDOL and putting:

```
CASE 
    WHEN SEDOL IS NULL THEN SecurityName 
    ELSE SEDOL
END
```

in my GROUP BY but with no success.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you try something like ISNULL(SEDOL,SecurityName) as Sese ... and change group by to group by WT.Sese

Comment: but i would need to return the SEDOLS in the final select and where it is null i would need to return a null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
;;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT 
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC,MAX(SecurityName)) AS [Rank]
            ,   ReportingDate
            ,   PortfolioID
            ,   PortfolioNme
            ,   MAX(SecurityName)                               AS SecurityName
            ,   CAST(SUM(Percentage) AS DECIMAL(22,1))          AS [Weight]
            ,   ISNULL(SEDOL, SecurityName) AS SEDOL
            ,   MAX(ISIN)                                       AS ISIN
        FROM @Worktable as WT

        WHERE WT.IssueType2 <> '010' AND WT.IssueType2 <> '055' AND WT.IssueType1 <> '110' -- To remove CASH and FX and Collateral

        GROUP BY    WT.ReportingDate
                ,   WT.PortfolioID
                ,   WT.PortfolioNme
                ,   ISNULL(WT.SEDOL, SecurityName)
    )

    SELECT 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR, ReportingDate, 103)  AS ReportingDate
        , PortfolioID                           AS FundCode
        , PortfolioNme                          AS FundName
        , SecurityName                          AS InstrumentName
        , [Rank]
        , [Weight]                              AS Percentage
        , SEDOL
        , ISIN
    FROM CTE

    WHERE [Rank] <= 10

    ORDER BY ReportingDate, PortfolioID, [Rank], [Weight] DESC
```

Comment: that was what i've just been trying.  For some reason the ISNULL is not working which i can't understand, even if i remove all aggregation and the group by i still can't get the ISNULL to work.

Comment: i changed the ISNULL(WT.SEDOL, SecurityName) to:

CASE WHEN SEDOL = '' THEN SecurityName ELSE SEDOL END

Thanks for your help, i knew it would be something easy

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want to simply add `AND WT.SEDOL is not null` in the CTE `WHERE` clause